# Terminal tab completion

Tags: macos, mac, autocomplete, readline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bash completion for commands in Mac OS](https://superuser.com/questions/288438/bash-completion-for-commands-in-mac-os)

I'm just moved from linux to mac, and one of the problems I'm having is that tab completion is only 1 level deep, and I'm not sure how to correct that.

Let me explain by example - when I used git on ubuntu, I'll start typing

```
$ git
```

and hit tab, and the shell would complete the command or display the options available for the letter\s I've typed. That's what happens on my mac as well (1 level). However, when I'd continue typing the next part of the command

```
$ git commit
```

and hit tab, mac terminal would not complete the next subcommand (for git) as it would in Linux. Same goes for other programs that support this multilevel command completion. I suspect this might be a readline library issue, but I'm not sure which one I should install.

Comment: It is not a readline issue (in fact, it is not an "issue"), it is because Ubuntu holds your hand with custom packages for bash.

Comment: This is definitely a bash configuration issue (since I get this behavior on mac + alot more that I have configured it for, like hostname completion) You should look around for power scripts for bash and add them to your profile.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Download [bash_completion](http://www.macports.org/) and source it from your `.bashrc`. Then put `contrib/completion/git-completion.bash` from the git distribution into `bash_completion.d`.

Alternatively you can install it via [MacPorts](http://www.caliban.org/bash/).

Comment: thanks, this worked. I added the following in my .bashrc

if [ -f /opt/local/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    source /opt/local/etc/bash_completion
fi

Comment: Even better, install it via homebrew: brew install bash-completion

Comment: @abyx: chosing the "better" between homebrew and macports is a _very_ subjective thing

Answer (score 2):

For git there is an option available on compilation to  support completion.

If you used port to install Git (which I recommend),
you can reinstall git with this command

```
sudo port install git-core +svn+bash_completion+doc
```

Which will install git with bash completion, git-svn support and docs