# Tab complete SCP with password

Tags: mac, ssh, terminal, autocomplete, scp

Is there any way to get tab completion to work in an SCP command if the target machine is behind a password?  I'm working in Terminal on OSX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to work with ssh-keys instead of a password-login.

See "[How do I set up SSH so I don't have to type my password?](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password)" to learn about how to do this.

Then, for example my zsh is able to complete the filenames on the remote host. Otherwise I would have to enter my password each time I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

For bash I assume you can install '[bash-completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/)' somehow, maybe "[Terminal tab completion](https://superuser.com/questions/53992/terminal-tab-completion)" will help.