# Bash completion for commands in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, macports, fink

How do I get `fink` and `macports` to autocomplete program names when typing commands, as in Ubuntu's `apt-get`?

For example when I type

```
sudo port install ca
```

and press <kbd>tab</kbd>, I want the terminal to autocomplete or show me the available commands.

OS X does not even auto-complete commands after `sudo`!

Answer (score 82, accepted):

[bash-completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org) adds completion for:

- Command names after `sudo` and `which`
- Macports and Homebrew package names (optional)
- Hostnames in `known_hosts` for commands like `ssh`
- Folders on `CDPATH`

And so on. You can print a list of completion commands with `complete -p` and see the source of a function with `declare -f`.

#### Installing Homebrew or MacPorts and Bash

First, you have to install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) according to the instructions. **Note:** Do not install both, as they conflict.

Then, install a newer version of Bash. The built-in Bash in OS X is a little old, and you'll get more completion options with Bash > 4.1, which you can get through

```
brew install bash
```

or

```
sudo port install bash
```

depending on whether you use Homebrew or MacPorts.

#### Installing bash-completion with Homebrew

To install `bash-completion`, you have to:

```
brew install bash-completion
```

And add the following to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```bsh
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Homebrew currently installs an older version of bash-completion (1.3) that still works with Bash 3.x, but still, using Bash 4.x is recommended.

#### Installing bash-completion with MacPorts

With MacPorts:

```
sudo port install bash-completion
```

Then, add to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f /opt/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh ]; then
  . /opt/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
fi
```

See [trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/bash-completion](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/bash-completion) for instructions on how to enable completion for port names.

Comment: MacPorts' `bash-completion` package provides support for completion of package names as additional arguments after `port <verb>`. See [here](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/sysutils/bash-completion/files/port), lines 48-58. This behavior is hinted at in [the MacPorts wiki](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/bash-completion), which states: "*This is not just for files and directories, but also e.g. for the commands of `port`. So you type `port <Tab>` and get a list of all possible commands.*", although it only explicitly mentions completion of the verbs (which is much simpler).

Comment: The package names *are* autocompleted, the wiki just doesn't mention that. See the linked script code.

Comment: The `variants.conf` is not for completion for MacPorts itself; variants.conf defines variants to automatically set for *all* ports, as is explained on the wiki page you linked. Adding that line causes bash completion support to be enabled when possible for ports you install.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about autocompletion in homebrew. That alone earned this answer an up-vote.

Comment: Excellent, this enabled `make` autocomplete, just what I wanted.

Comment: if you happen to have both Brew and MacPorts make sure to add the macports one before Brew as it checks for $BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR and exits if populated.

Comment: _excellent_ instructions here!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @slhck! I still wanted auto-complete for Git and I found a good solution here https://www.macinstruct.com/tutorials/how-to-enable-git-tab-autocomplete-on-your-mac/