# Similar command suggestion in terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

In ubuntu (and likely elsewhere), if I misspell a command, the shell suggests similarly spelled commands:

```
askewchan@foppl:~$ exi
No command 'exi' found, did you mean:
 Command 'ex' from package 'vim' (main)
 Command 'exif' from package 'exif' (universe)
 Command 'exim' from package 'exim4-daemon-heavy' (main)
 Command 'exim' from package 'exim4-daemon-light' (main)
 Command 'esi' from package 'atm-tools' (universe)
 Command 'kexi' from package 'kexi' (main)
 Command 'exp' from package 'alliance' (universe)
 Command 'axi' from package 'afnix' (universe)
exi: command not found
```

(which didn't work in this case, as I had intended to type `exit`). Apparently this comes from `apt-get install command-not-found`, but is there something like this for OS X?

Is there anything similar that would work on OS X or bash in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, unless you have fink, brew or macports installed, there isn't a repository for bash to search.  Except there kind of is - fish searches man page descriptions (kind of like apropos).

http://fishshell.com/ has "man page completions" which seems relevant:

"Other shells support programmable completions, but only fish generates them automatically by parsing your installed man pages. "

Or zsh has auto-predictions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223388/fish-style-autosuggestion-in-zsh

If you're ok with hitting tab, which might prevent the typo in the first place?

You can do auto-completion in bash, though it's not as sophisticated as zsh:

[Bash completion for commands in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/288438/bash-completion-for-commands-in-mac-os)

Comment: There must already be the list of executables in `PATH` or something simpler, how else do all the command autocomplete?  To be clear, I don't expect it to search uninstalled packages, just commands that exist.  `git` does this as well, actually.